# How to smooth the painting of a custom QML element?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, shader, qtquick2

I try now to create custom QML element, derived from `QQuickItem`. So I overrided `QQuickItem::updatePaintNode` and want now do draw a line. My code:

```js
QSGNode *StrikeLine::updatePaintNode(QSGNode *oldNode, QQuickItem::UpdatePaintNodeData *)
{
    QSGGeometryNode *node = 0;

    QSGGeometry *geometry;
    QSGFlatColorMaterial *material;
    node = static_cast<QSGGeometryNode *>(oldNode);
    if(!node) {
        node = new QSGGeometryNode;
        geometry = new QSGGeometry(QSGGeometry::defaultAttributes_Point2D(), 2);
        geometry->setDrawingMode(GL_LINES);
        geometry->setLineWidth(3);
        material = new QSGFlatColorMaterial;
        material->setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0));
        node->setGeometry(geometry);
        node->setFlag(QSGNode::OwnsGeometry);
        node->setMaterial(material);
        node->setFlag(QSGNode::OwnsMaterial);
        getColor();
    } else {
        geometry = node->geometry();
        material = static_cast<QSGFlatColorMaterial *>(node->material());
    }
    geometry->vertexDataAsPoint2D()[0].set(p_startPoint.x(), p_startPoint.y());
    geometry->vertexDataAsPoint2D()[1].set(p_endPoint.x(), p_endPoint.y());
    material->setColor(getColor());
    node->markDirty(QSGNode::DirtyGeometry);

    return node;
}
```

But my line looks so ugly. The edges are rough and it looks like DOS graphics at all. So my question - how can I apply smooth painting? I now it may be some shader or something but I cannot find any documentation.

Comment: I think [antialiasing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#antialiasing-prop) is set to false by default, resulting in aliased lines. Try to set it to `true`. By the way, why not using `QQuickPaintedItem`? That would be easier/safer, see [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-customitems-painteditem-example.html).

Comment: `QQuickPaintedItem` is too slow due to double painting. Yes, it may be useful for small or not complicated scenes but by target platform is Android and I want to do it as fast as possible.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The scene graph supports two types of antialiasing. Primitives such as rectangles and images will be antialiased by adding more vertices along the edge of the primitives so that the edges fade to transparent. This method called vertex antialiasing. If you requests a multisampled OpenGL context, the scene graph will prefer multisample based antialiasing (MSAA).

Vertex antialiasing can produce seams between edges of adjacent primitives, even when the two edges are mathmatically the same. Multisample antialiasing does not.

### Multisample Antialiasing

Multisample antialiasing is a hardware feature where the hardware calculates a coverage value per pixel in the primitive. Some hardware can multisample at a very low cost, while other hardware may need both more memory and more GPU cycles to render a frame.

To enable multisample antialiasing you should set `QSurfaceFormat` with samples greater than 0 using `QQuickWindow::setFormat()`

```
QQuickView view;
QSurfaceFormat format = view.format();
format.setSamples(16);
view.setFormat(format);
view.show();
```

### Vertex Antialiasing

Vertex antialiasing can be enabled and disabled on a per-item basis using the `Item::antialiasing` property. It will work regardless of what the underlying hardware supports and produces higher quality antialiasing, both for normally rendered primitives and also for primitives captured into framebuffer objects.

The downside to using vertex antialiasing is that each primitive with antialiasing enabled will have to be blended. In terms of [batching](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph-renderer.html), this means that the renderer needs to do more work to figure out if the primitive can be batched or not and due to overlaps with other elements in the scene, it may also result in less batching, which could impact performance.

---

To apply vertex antialiasing to custom QML element, derived from `QQuickItem`, follow next steps:

1) Create custom material and OpenGL shader program.

**smoothcolormaterial.h**

```
#include <QSGMaterial>
#include <QSGMaterialShader>

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class QSGSmoothColorMaterial : public QSGMaterial
{
public:
    QSGSmoothColorMaterial();
    int compare(const QSGMaterial *other) const;
protected:
    virtual QSGMaterialType *type() const;
    virtual QSGMaterialShader *createShader() const;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class QSGSmoothColorMaterialShader : public QSGMaterialShader
{
public:
    QSGSmoothColorMaterialShader();
    virtual void updateState(const RenderState &state, QSGMaterial *newEffect, QSGMaterial *oldEffect);
    virtual char const *const *attributeNames() const;
private:
    void initialize();
    int m_matrixLoc;
    int m_opacityLoc;
    int m_pixelSizeLoc;
};
```

**smoothcolormaterial.cpp**

```
QSGSmoothColorMaterial::QSGSmoothColorMaterial()
{
    setFlag(RequiresFullMatrixExceptTranslate, true);
    setFlag(Blending, true);
}

int QSGSmoothColorMaterial::compare(const QSGMaterial *other) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(other)
    return 0;
}

QSGMaterialType *QSGSmoothColorMaterial::type() const
{
    static QSGMaterialType type;
    return &type;
}

QSGMaterialShader *QSGSmoothColorMaterial::createShader() const
{
    return new QSGSmoothColorMaterialShader();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

QSGSmoothColorMaterialShader::QSGSmoothColorMaterialShader()
    : QSGMaterialShader()
{
    setShaderSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, QStringLiteral(":/shaders/smoothcolor.vert"));
    setShaderSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, QStringLiteral(":/shaders/smoothcolor.frag"));
}

void QSGSmoothColorMaterialShader::updateState(const QSGMaterialShader::RenderState &state, QSGMaterial *newEffect, QSGMaterial *oldEffect)
{
    Q_UNUSED(newEffect)

    if (state.isOpacityDirty())
        program()->setUniformValue(m_opacityLoc, state.opacity());

    if (state.isMatrixDirty())
        program()->setUniformValue(m_matrixLoc, state.combinedMatrix());

    if (oldEffect == 0) {
        // The viewport is constant, so set the pixel size uniform only once.
        QRect r = state.viewportRect();
        program()->setUniformValue(m_pixelSizeLoc, 2.0f / r.width(), 2.0f / r.height());
    }
}

const char * const *QSGSmoothColorMaterialShader::attributeNames() const
{
    static char const *const attributes[] = {
        "vertex",
        "vertexColor",
        "vertexOffset",
        0
    };
    return attributes;
}

void QSGSmoothColorMaterialShader::initialize()
{
    m_matrixLoc = program()->uniformLocation("matrix");
    m_opacityLoc = program()->uniformLocation("opacity");
    m_pixelSizeLoc = program()->uniformLocation("pixelSize");
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
varying lowp vec4 color;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

**Vertex Shader**

```
uniform highp vec2 pixelSize;
uniform highp mat4 matrix;
uniform lowp float opacity;

attribute highp vec4 vertex;
attribute lowp vec4 vertexColor;
attribute highp vec2 vertexOffset;

varying lowp vec4 color;

void main()
{
    highp vec4 pos = matrix * vertex;
    gl_Position = pos;

    if (vertexOffset.x != 0.) {
        highp vec4 delta = matrix[0] * vertexOffset.x;
        highp vec2 dir = delta.xy * pos.w - pos.xy * delta.w;
        highp vec2 ndir = .5 * pixelSize * normalize(dir / pixelSize);
        dir -= ndir * delta.w * pos.w;
        highp float numerator = dot(dir, ndir * pos.w * pos.w);
        highp float scale = 0.0;
        if (numerator < 0.0)
            scale = 1.0;
        else
            scale = min(1.0, numerator / dot(dir, dir));
        gl_Position += scale * delta;
    }

    if (vertexOffset.y != 0.) {
        highp vec4 delta = matrix[1] * vertexOffset.y;
        highp vec2 dir = delta.xy * pos.w - pos.xy * delta.w;
        highp vec2 ndir = .5 * pixelSize * normalize(dir / pixelSize);
        dir -= ndir * delta.w * pos.w;
        highp float numerator = dot(dir, ndir * pos.w * pos.w);
        highp float scale = 0.0;
        if (numerator < 0.0)
            scale = 1.0;
        else
            scale = min(1.0, numerator / dot(dir, dir));
        gl_Position += scale * delta;
    }

    color = vertexColor * opacity;
}
```

2) Create custom `AttributeSet` for `QSGGeometry`.

**myquickitem.cpp**

```
namespace
{
    struct Color4ub
    {
        unsigned char r, g, b, a;
    };

    inline Color4ub colorToColor4ub(const QColor &c)
    {
        Color4ub color = { uchar(c.redF() * c.alphaF() * 255),
                           uchar(c.greenF() * c.alphaF() * 255),
                           uchar(c.blueF() * c.alphaF() * 255),
                           uchar(c.alphaF() * 255)
                         };
        return color;
    }

    struct SmoothVertex
    {
        float x, y;
        Color4ub color;
        float dx, dy;
        void set(float nx, float ny, Color4ub ncolor, float ndx, float ndy)
        {
            x = nx; y = ny; color = ncolor;
            dx = ndx; dy = ndy;
        }
    };

    const QSGGeometry::AttributeSet &smoothAttributeSet()
    {
        static QSGGeometry::Attribute data[] = {
            QSGGeometry::Attribute::create(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, true),
            QSGGeometry::Attribute::create(1, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, false),
            QSGGeometry::Attribute::create(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, false)
        };
        static QSGGeometry::AttributeSet attrs = { 3, sizeof(SmoothVertex), data };
        return attrs;
    }
}
```

3) Apply custom material and custom geometry to `QSGGeometryNode`.

**myquickitem.cpp**

```
QSGNode *MyQuickItem::updatePaintNode(QSGNode *oldNode, QQuickItem::UpdatePaintNodeData *data)
{
     QSGGeometryNode *node = 0;

     QSGGeometry *geometry;
     QSGSmoothColorMaterial *material;
     node = static_cast<QSGGeometryNode *>(oldNode);
     if(!node) {
         node = new QSGGeometryNode;
         geometry = new QSGGeometry(smoothAttributeSet(), 0);
         geometry->setDrawingMode(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
         material = new QSGSmoothColorMaterial();
         node->setGeometry(geometry);
         node->setFlag(QSGNode::OwnsGeometry);
         node->setMaterial(material);
         node->setFlag(QSGNode::OwnsMaterial);
     } else {
         geometry = node->geometry();
         material = static_cast<QSGSmoothColorMaterial *>(node->material());
     }
```

4) Get pointer to vertex data.

```
 int vertexStride = geometry->sizeOfVertex();
 int vertexCount = 8;

 geometry->allocate(vertexCount, 0);
 SmoothVertex *smoothVertices = reinterpret_cast<SmoothVertex *>(geometry->vertexData());
 memset(smoothVertices, 0, vertexCount * vertexStride);
```

5) Set vertex data.

You need 4 points.

```
 float lineWidth = 4;
 float tlX = 0;   float tlY = 0;               //top-left
 float blX = 0;   float blY = 0 + lineWidth;   //bottom-left
 float trX = 500; float trY = 100;             //top-right
 float brX = 500; float brY = 100 + lineWidth; //bottom-right
 float delta = lineWidth * 0.5f;

 Color4ub fillColor = colorToColor4ub(QColor(255,0,0,255));
 Color4ub transparent = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

To draw antialiased line you should set 8 vertices to draw 6 triangles(2 for line, 4 for antialiasing). Vertices 0 and 2, 1 and 3, 4 and 6, 5 and 7 have the same coordinates, but different color and opposite vertex offset.

[image]

```
 smoothVertices[0].set(trX, trY, transparent, delta, -delta);
 smoothVertices[1].set(tlX, tlY, transparent, -delta, -delta);

 smoothVertices[2].set(trX, trY, fillColor, -delta, delta);
 smoothVertices[3].set(tlX, tlY, fillColor, delta, delta);
 smoothVertices[4].set(brX, brY, fillColor, -delta, -delta);
 smoothVertices[5].set(blX, blY, fillColor, delta, -delta);

 smoothVertices[6].set(brX, brY, transparent, delta, delta);
 smoothVertices[7].set(blX, blY, transparent, -delta, delta);


 node->markDirty(QSGNode::DirtyGeometry);

 return node;
 }
```

Comment: Since multisampling anyhow has a non-negligible cost, the alternative is providing a small border for the main geometry that fades to transparent.That's f.i. what Rectangle does in QQ2.

Comment: Thanks, @Meefte, that's works. But I doubt that method sets it fot all the scene, not for specified items only.

Comment: Thanks, @peppe. Yes, I've checked the source of `Rectangle` element. it uses `QSGRectangleNode` to draw itself, witch it its turn uses some smooth shader. But it's  .... ufff ... so hard to understand how it all works. May be you have some example?

Comment: Great answer! Is it possible to reuse parts of `QSGRectangleNode` implementation? like the material or the attributes for example?

Comment: If someone has trouble setting the format for multisampling because they use QQmlApplicationEngine instead of QQuickView, you need to use `QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat()` as seen on [this Qt example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-gallery-main-cpp.html)

Comment: Your answer is very good. It is exactly what Qt documentation is missing about this class. I've made it working on desktop, but for some reason it doesn't work on iOS. I've simplifed the fragment shader to just paint a solid color and nothings gets painted on iOS. Do you have any clue? Thanks once again for this incredible answer!